# Content types and site columns went missing in a site collection

Tags: content-type, site-collection, publishing-site, site-column

I migrated a web application from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016. After migration I was able to see the content types and site columns and everything was fine.

I took a template of a publishing site and while creating the site I got an error message, some features are missing. Later when I was going through the site collection and found that the content types and the site columns are missing.

I used below link to take publishing site template.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2013/06/13/save-sharepoint-2013-publishing-site-as-a-template/

Please let me know if anybody faced this issue? What could be the resolution?

Comment: You need to install the WSP solution to make sure the content types and site columns are present.

Comment: It is not related to any solution. All the default SharePoint content types and site columns are also missing. Site content types page is completely empty.

Comment: Oops, but I remember saving publishing site as a template was never supported.